# Cuda libraries not found for cuda 11 for ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, cuda, nvidia

I am using Nvidia VM on Azure with Ubuntu 20.04 I already had nvidia and cuda installed but hile running my program it still showed libraries not found

`nvidia-smi`

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.103.01   Driver Version: 470.103.01   CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla T4            Off  | 00000001:00:00.0 Off |                  Off |
| N/A   32C    P0    25W /  70W |      0MiB / 16127MiB |      6%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This is the error I see for multiple cuda libraries:

```
Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-05-02 05:33:53.131224: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-05-02 05:33:53.131235: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:30] Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
Could not load dynamic library 'libcudnn.so.7'; dlerror: libcudnn.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-05-02 05:33:55.738515: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1592] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries.
```

I am not sure if this error is because of GPG key error rotation or something else, since i tried to install driver separately as well but it kept giving error of not locating drivers.

I also tried:

```
sudo apt-get -y install cuda

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have

requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable

distribution that some required packages have not yet been created

or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

cuda : Depends: cuda-11-6 (>= 11.6.2) but it is not going to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am using tensorflow-gpu-2.1.3 as thats the requirement for my program.

I have posted this on nvidia forum as well.

Answer (score 0):

What I can offer as solution options:

1. Google your question with different combinations. (This issue could also be related to the correct 'libcudnn.so.7' driver path, which it probably is)
   With `libcudnn.so.7` seen in the error dump
   Is the `CUDA Version: 11.4` seen in the result of `nvidia-smi` really the same?
   You must be sure of that.
2. Using the ready-made nvidia-docker plugin, you can find tensorflow, torch, etc containers ready and working. The current `nvidi-smi` dump indicates that this is possible.
3. It is possible to have more stable and complete development environments with different packaging and configuration systems such as anaconda and miniconda. If necessary, you may have, 3 different TF and Cuda versions, by using environments.